# Sublime Text 2 RubyTest problems, no output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext, ruby-test

When I run RubyTest with Command-Shift-R, it gives this output:

```
DEBUG_EXEC: cd ~/Documents/ProgrammingGeneral/rails/sample_app/ && rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb -l 54
reloading ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/RubyTest.last-run
```

This file has contents:

```
{
    "last_test_file": "static_pages_spec.rb",
    "last_test_run": "cd ~/Documents/ProgrammingGeneral/rails/sample_app/ && rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb -l 54" 
}
```

I never get the results of my tests. I can run them manually in the console, and with Guard (which I kill before I run RubyTest). I'm also running Spork.

Also, I've been getting a lot of output of the form `scan: ~/Library/Application Support/path/to/stuff has been seen before, skipping`.

The same thing happens with `Command-shift-T`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and was able to solve it by running Sublime Text 2 from the command line.

I added Sublime to my /usr/bin folder using a symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl subl
```

Then start Sublime Text 2 by running `subl` on the command line. You could also just run:

```
 /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```